# python3: howto use same class instance from different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

e.g. f1.py  (simplified):

```
...
class TestClass:
    x = 0

...
```

and f2.py :

```
from f1 import *
tc = TestClass()

tc.x = 73
```

and f3.py :

```
from f1 import *
...
print(tc.x)
...
```

Of course this is wrong, but how to do it right?
Well, I simply need access to data and functions in the same instance of a class from different files, comparable to e.g. 'extern' in C. Generating a new instance in every file will generate different variables, is therefore not applicable. Thanks for help.

Comment: Now here is an example of too *little* code. What is really in `f3.py` which wants to access `tc.x`?

Comment: is there a reason you can't import f2 instead of f1 in f3?

Comment: while it's not particularly clear what you're trying to do, if as it appears you want a "singleton" instance then why not just put`tc = TestClass()` at the bottom of `f1.py` and simply import that in the other files, rather than the class itself? (Unfortunately Python does not allow you to choose not to export the class, as many other languages do.)

Comment: Thanks; comments and answers helped me to understand. So I use the easier and  sufficient method with `tc = TestClass()` in f1.py and import f1 to other files where needed. Thanks for the fast help

Comment: @quamrana: The project consists because of its size  about 10 different files, most of them with access to data and methods of the same class. I like to use classes to make modules better portable. Maybe I went a bit too far in reducing the description, f3.py is a placeholder for more files with the same functionality.

Comment: Ok, so what, typically, in `f3.py` (or other files) needs to access `tc.x` and why?

Comment: well, I have some kind of global status variables and methods used by different programs/tasks stored in several files (for size and thematic).  All need the same data/methods. Basically I think of some kind of C/C++ e.g. 'struct' construction; maybe not 'pythonian', - so my question arose.

Answer (score 2):

Just import `f2.py`:

```py
from f2 import tc
...
print(tc.x)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a singleton class as your TestClass.
Following is a link with pattern implementation in python that you can follow.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_singleton.htm